# Routes not working on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have this route defined  `Route::resource('smn','smnController');`

And this controller `smnController` which as following code.

```
public function index()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

In console when I type `php artisan routes`, it displays

`GET|HEAD smn            | smn.index   | smnController@index`

along with many others.

In the url when I type `http://localhost:8081/laravel/smn`, it displays error not found.

But when I change route to `Route::resource('/','smnController');`, and url to `http://localhost:8081/laravel/` it displays `helo`.

Can anyone please explain this

**EDIT**

complete route and controller

```
<?php

Route::resource('smn','smnController');

?>
```

AND COntroller

```
<?php

class smnController extends BaseController {



    public function index()
    {
        return "hello";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: can you please show the controller code and the router (complete). if there is anything that match before the resource, it will route it.

Comment: @LeaTano the edit is made to display the complete code.

Comment: try this http://localhost:8081/laravel/public/smn if you have not made any changes to htaccess for removing public from url

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a LAMP stack then you should enable the rewrite module, type `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to enable that module, also make sure you are using the mcrypt extension of php typing `sudo php5enmod mcrypt` and then restart the apache service `sudo service apache2 restart` that should work

Answer (score 0):

in your VirtualHost please make sure your `DocumentRoot` is pointing to `public`

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public
```

Comment: this path is just an example, please match your path

Comment: Where do i find this file to make the change.

Comment: what are you using? LAMP ? XAMPP? WAMP?

Comment: C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.21/conf/httpd.conf (your Apache version number may be different)

Comment: after you did the change, restart apache. If you have multiple domains you can setup multiple virtualhosts. Read this page. It explain really well how to setup Virtual Host: http://www.kristengrote.com/blog/articles/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-wamp

Comment: NO still not working..I think I am going to uninstall wamp and install again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71223/discussion-between-lea-tano-and-chelsea).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Route::get('/', 'smnController@index');


class smnController extends BaseController {



    public function index()
    {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```